# C++, Make action after square-bracket setter

Tags: c++, setter

I'd like to implement simple database for practice, but I cant find solution for one problem. Let's we have something like:

```
template <class T> class simpleDB
{
public:
    string pathToFile;
    void writeToFile();
    vector<T> base;

    //setter for "base"
    //getter for "base"
}
```

Thing I wish is to call writeToFile() after each square-bracket setter call, so the question is: "How should I write such []setter?".

There are a lot of setter examples on google but none of them avail to call something after returning reference for vector member.
Note that T supposed to be any custom complex struct, ex:

```
struct point
{
    int x,y;
}
```

Thanks

UPD: as asked, I'd like to use this thing as(I skip part with allocating of first element, since its not a question):

```
simpleDB<point> db;
db[0].x = 1;
db[0].y = 1;
```

Comment: Please post some example code of how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a proxy class with an assignment operator.

```
template <class T> class simpleDB {
    // ...

    class Proxy {
        simpleDB& db;
        size_t i;
        Proxy& operator=(T t) {
            // If you want to auto-allocate the slot...
            if (db.base.size() <= i) db.base.resize(i + 1);
            db.base[i] = t;
            db.writeToFile();
            return *this;
        }
        T operator*() const { return db.base.at(i); }
    };

    Proxy operator[](size_t i) { return {*this, i}; }
    const Proxy operator[](size_t i) const { return {*this, i}; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw such solution but it wont work for me. I have updated my post with desired usage samples. I just tried your solution again, but I can't compile it now. MSVC says: ['x': is not a member of 'simpleDB<point>::Proxy'] on line [db[0].x=1]. What I missing this way?=/

Comment: @Archan What you're asking for isn't possible without turning `struct point` itself into a rich class with similar proxying capability.

Comment: So I should extend my 'point'? Am I get you right? Sorry for troubling you, but can you describe this a little more? Which way should I modify it?

Comment: @Archan no, you should just live with a single level proxy and do assignments via `db[0] = {1, 2}`.

Comment: @Archan no probs!